References do not show in beamer presentation
Here is my main.tex file
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{Presentation}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
  \input{Presentation} %this is my content file with all the different slides
\end{document}

and this is my Presentation .tex file which has all the contents
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

%...multiple frames with content

\begin{frame}
 hello test \cite{kentta2006latex}
\end{frame}

%and lastly 

\begin{frame}{References}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

this is my references.bib file
@article{kentta2006latex,
  title={Latex uniformity in the coating layer of paper},
  author={Kentt{\"a}, Eija and P{\"o}hler, Tiina and Juvonen, Kari},
  journal={Nordic Pulp \& Paper Research Journal},
  volume={21},
  number={5},
  pages={665--669},
  year={2006},
  publisher={De Gruyter}
}
@book{griffiths2016learning,
  title={Learning LaTeX},
  author={Griffiths, David F and Higham, Desmond J},
  year={2016},
  publisher={SIAM}
}

No matter what I solution I employ from stackoverflow, the references slide simply does not show up.
I get the frame containing the citation as : hello test [kentta2006latex]
and different warning every time depending on which solution I employ. Right now, I get the warning "Presentation.tex: warning: 563: Citation `kentta2006latex' on page 68 undefined"
and "Presentation.tex: error: 567: Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}".
My texstudio (on Macbook) default configurations are:

Can someone please help me out with this? I am at my wit's end.
Edit: to show .blg file as per request
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - This is Biber 2.17
[0] Config.pm:310> INFO - Logfile is 'sac.blg'
[53] biber-darwin:340> INFO - === Mon Oct 14, 2024, 12:06:07
[66] Biber.pm:418> INFO - Reading 'sac.bcf'
[144] Biber.pm:972> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[157] Biber.pm:4383> INFO - Processing section 0
[166] Biber.pm:4574> INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'references.bib' for section 0
[166] bibtex.pm:1713> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[172] bibtex.pm:1518> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'
[199] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[199] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[199] Biber.pm:4203> INFO - Sorting list 'apa/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'apa' and locale 'en-US'
[199] Biber.pm:4209> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
[201] bbl.pm:654> INFO - Writing 'sac.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[201] bbl.pm:757> INFO - Output to sac.bbl

Edit: the only fixaround I can find to the problem is to change style=apa to the biblatex file. otherwise the code simply does not show references with any other style. I'd appreciate any help in understanding why this happens.

You need to compile with biber, not bibtex

There is also one } too much at the end of your bib file

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i followed these instructions in the link that you mentioned and i still receive the same two warning and error messages as i stated in my original post.

Did you correct the syntax error?

yes i have, it was an error i made while writing the post.

Can you show your .log and .blg files?

Please also update the image of your preferences. It still shows bibtex.

thank you, i have posted the .blg file - but the .log file is to large for me to screenshot and post

Please don't post as screenshot. Instead post it in a code block.

Ok, the blg looks fine. Did you run pdflatex once more? Are there any errors in the .log file?

your code compiles fine here and produces the reference on the final slide as expected. can you try copying your code back into an empty directory and compiling just the example you've given us? I compiled with pdflatex + biber + pdflatex.

@cfr seems like your suggestion works when i do it on a brand new latex project. I still don't understand why it doesn't work for my initial file that I had been working on. Oh well, I'll just transfer (copy) everything into a new project.
